# Style xml fragment as a table

Tags: css, xml

I'm wondering how to correctly style this XML clip to be put in a table. The columns are the headings for the data that will be added below under each heading in the table. each column ex (symbol, name, etc) is appearing vertically I need each column horizontal what am I doing wrong?

Heres the css clip

```
titles {
    display: table;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

column {
    display: table-column;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#c1 {
    color:green
}
```

And heres the xml clip

```
<heading>NASDAQ 100</heading>
   <subHeading>Current quotes</subHeading>
   <dateTime>
      <date>11/01/2008</date>
      <time>11:45:05</time>
   </dateTime>

   <titles>
      <column id="c1">Symbol</column>
      <column id="c2">Name</column>
      <column id="c3">Last Sale</column>
      <column id="c4">Net Change</column>
      <column id="c5">% Change</column>
      <column id="c6">Volume</column>
   </titles>
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: You want a 1 row table?

Comment: the problem is i don't know how to style each specific column tag